# Styling TextBox/PasswordBox in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I've been wondering if there is a simpler way to change just one attribute then restyling the whole ControlTemplate in Windows Phone 8.

I recently found myself in need to change PasswordBox's background (the background shown when selected/typing into it) without changing anything else. I know there is the way of recreating the whole ControlTemplate (since it's HUGE for my taste and I'm getting a bit lost in it - I'm a rookie).

**Are the other (preferably easier) options how to do it? If so, which?**

The reason I'm asking is because I'm creating App that needs to look pretty much the same on Android, iOS and Windows Phone (android & iOS apps are done by someone else, I'm working on WP App and the design is given).

The App needs to look the same regardles of theme chosen by user on his phone.

And since the text is white and in dark theme when writing into TextBox/PasswordBox, the background is also changed to white - the result being you can't see what you're typing.

[image: Example]

**Is it easier to change "Foreground-when-typing" or "background-when-typing"? How to do it without recreating the whole ControlTemplate?**

Comment: Background property should be fine. Background="yourColor" in XAML.

Comment: The background property does not solve my problem. I need to change "background-when-typing", not just the background.

Comment: When you're typing it means that the control is focused. So at GotFocus event, change the background. At LostFocus, return to the initial background. Or is this not enough as well?

Comment: That should do it. :) The way you formulated your answer the first time it sounded like you misunderstood the question.

Comment: Even though It's not exactly a good solution, because that would leave me overriding every textbox's GetFocus & LostFocus methods in entire app, that's why I'm looking for a styling solution.

Comment: But you can reuse the same event handler for all textboxes. Or you could create a custom control with only one textbox/passwordbox that behaves exactly the same but has those Gotfocus/LostFocus events implemented in your specific manner.

Comment: The second solution might be an answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41106/discussion-between-vasile-marian-flma-and-mishan)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do this is with retemplating and implicit styling.

Don't be scared. It's easy, see, here's what you're after:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <!--<VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>-->
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="ReadonlyBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Now, whenever using a TextBox on that page it will always be white text on a black background. (Or reversed when selected.)

This:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="something" />
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Creates this:

[image: Example of implicity styled TextBoxes that always look the same]

Unfortunately you can't do anything about the handles on the selection using the accent color though.

I haven't handed disabled or read-only states but they should be simple to change.